# What would be the regex expression for some string not followed a few strings

Tags: regex, pycharm, webstorm

I want to find all occurrences of `log.` not followed by `warning`, `info`, `error` or `debug`

I have this so far. But it does not seem to work

`log.([^(debug)]&[^(warning)]&[^(error)]&[^(info)])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **negative lookahead** for this:

```
log\.(?!(?:debug|warning|error|info)).*
```

Your use of negation in character class is incorrect in your regex:

```
log.([^(debug)]&[^(warning)]&[^(error)]&[^(debug)])
```

Since inside character class every character is checked individually not as a string.

Comment: This stack overflow has a new rule I think. It is not allowing me to accept your answer for another 8 minutes

Comment: Yes I think they have 10 min limit in place before you can accept an answer.

Comment: That is stupid however. The explanation is not very sound 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81203/you-can-accept-this-answer-in-10-minutes

Comment: I think they want to allow some extra time for other people to answer on the same question.

Comment: @anubhava please replace one duplicated "debug" by "info" in yout regexp :)